# FlatFileItemWriter not enclosing quote character when delimiter in value

Tags: spring, spring-batch

According to the documentation [setQuoteCharacter](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/current/api/org/springframework/batch/item/file/transform/DelimitedLineTokenizer.html#setQuoteCharacter-char-) the output will be enclosed with quotes if there is a delimiter in the value, I don't see this happening, what am I doing wrong?

```
@Bean
@StepScope
public FlatFileItemWriter<Customer> csvWriter(@Value("#{jobParameters['csvOutputFile']}") Resource outputFile) {
    return new FlatFileItemWriterBuilder<Customer>()
            .name("csvWriter")
            .resource(outputFile)
            .delimited()
            .names("email","owner","address",)
            .build();
}
```

Doesn't the .delimited() returning FlatFileItemWriterBuilder.DelimitedBuilder not utilize the default values in DelimitedLineTokenizer?

pom.xml using SpringBoot 2.2.6.RELEASE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Doesn't the .delimited() returning FlatFileItemWriterBuilder.DelimitedBuilder not utilize the default values in DelimitedLineTokenizer?

No, it does not. This would mean that by default, writing a delimited file encloses each field in `"` which is not a good default IMO. BTW, there is an [feature request](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/issues/1139) to add support for quote chars in `DelimitedLineAggregator`.

Comment: It would be useful if quotes are included by default only for fields that contains the delimiter. I can see it might not be favorable for all use-cases.